# Can I install Yaourt on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I saw [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/yaourt) saying *"yaourt is a standard installer in distros Manjaro and archLinux and popular in Ubuntu too"*. Does this mean that I can install **Yaourt** on **Ubuntu**? And, if yes, how could I install **Yaourt** on **Ubuntu**?

Answer (score 3):

Yaourt is the front-end for the pacman package manager, so in order to get yaourt you would need to install pacman.

Sadly you can't just `apt-get install pacman`; you'd have to compile it, then you'd have to compile yaourt.

Using a different package manager than the one made for the specific distribution is a terrible idea and will lead to many problems in future.

Yaourt supports AUR - all it does is git clone and then compile the package for you.

Ubuntu has a similar thing in the form of PPAs.

If you want detailed information on how to make pacman and yaourt run on Ubuntu I will help you, but I warn you that it will cause you nothing but pain and frustration and lead to a broken system.

Comment: Thanks for the long-version answer, but I don't still understand what means "yaourt is a standard installer ... popular in Ubuntu too" in Ubuntu wiki. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: honestly no idea what they meant last time i used ubuntu was back in 2008